# Chrome browser: How to find tabs with unsaved changes

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

For tabs with unsaved changes, I meant:

When you try to close a tab with unsaved changes, it shows a warning:

```
Leave site?
Changes you made may not be saved.
```

We could have multiple unsaved changes.  The question is, how do I find them?

Currently, I can only find them by hitting the close tab button, one tab by one tab. And I inevitably closed those tabs I still need.

Or, of course I can type

```
chrome://restart/
```

on the address bar, so that, on exiting chrome, it closed one tab by one tab: the unsaved changes will be detected in the process.  However, I don't really want to start chrome or close any tab.